# How to understand the meaning of function definition highlights in VS Code?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I wrote the following code snipped in VSC:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(Math.max(...a))
```

If you hover over `max`, VSC gives you it's definition as:

```
(method) Math.max(...values: number[]): number
Returns the larger of a set of supplied numeric expressions.

@param values — Numeric expressions to be evaluated.
```

[Screenshot of the definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG2qS.png)

What does `(...values: number[]): number` mean? Does that mean that it takes in an array and stores it as an array called `number[]` internally?  Also, what does `@param values` mean?

Comment: See [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: also check [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/)

Comment: @jakarta By the way, the "definition highlights" come from IntelliSense, which is a feature powered by the TypeScript Language Server using the Language Server Protocol (LSP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does `(...values: number[]): number` mean?

This uses [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and just means that all of the parameters are of the same type: `number`. The [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) type of the function is also `number`.

This syntax `value: type` comes from [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

> Does that mean that it takes in an array and stores it as an array called `number[]` internally?

If you were to implement [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) yourself using this signature, then yes, all of the arguments passed to the function would be stored in a variable called `values`, which would be an array of numbers.

> Also, what does `@param values` mean?

This is [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) syntax, and it refers to a [function parameter](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html).

Answer (score 0):

> What does `(...values: number[]): number` mean?

It means it's a function that takes as many numbers as you want, each as separate parameters (ie, you can call `Math.max(1, 2)`, or `Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, etc), and it returns a number

> Does that mean that it takes in an array and stores it as an array called number[] internally?

No, it says nothing about the internal implementation, and no array needs to be involved. It's just telling you how you can use this function

> Also, what does `@param values` mean?

To a human, it just means "this function takes a parameter called `values`". Some automated tools look for the keyword `@param` as part of [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc)

Comment: What about the `number[]` part?

Comment: As i mentioned, it means "as many numbers as you want" in this context. The `[]` is referring to an array, but due to the `...` it's not going to be a single parameter, but spread across multiple.